# Node app can't authenticate and connect postgres docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

So I'm trying to get a node app to connect and authenticate properly to a postgres db running in docker. I'm supposed to run a script that adds data to one of the dbs I add to the container but it's keep throwing this error:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "myuser"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ migrate: `knex migrate:latest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ migrate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     .../.npm/_logs/2021-03-30T21_21_55_132Z-debug.log
```

According to the instructions in the github I'm supposed to create a postgres container using this:

`docker run --name "postgres" -e POSTGRES_USER='{add-postgres-user}' -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD='{add-postgres-password}' -p 5432:5432 -d -t kartoza/postgis:12.4`

I'm able to connect to it using psql and perform queries on it ok with the password and user I entered. However when I enter the same information in an `env` file the script reads it fails:

```
POSTGRES_HOST=172.17.0.2
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=myuser
POSRGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSRGRES_DATABASE=db_example
```

I've tried changing `POSTGRES_HOST` to things like localhost, the container name, 127.0.0.1 but no matter what I change it to it fails. I made sure the db was entered like the instructions said. I'm not sure if it has to do with the host binding of the docker image but I thought the 172 address it runs on is the right one. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with node 14.16.0.

Comment: Typo strikes again: POSTGRES_USER vs "POSR" GRES PASSWORD

Comment: Wow... Major derp moment

Comment: He's right. Check exactly the two **ENV VARS**. You have typo.

Comment: Yea fixing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Robert Kawecki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879220/node-app-cant-authenticate-and-connect-postgres-docker-container#comment118220827_66879220), the last two environment variables have typos:

> **POSRGRES**_PASSWORD=password

> **POSRGRES**_DATABASE=db_example